# Blazor: Fire event when user has reached bottom

Tags: c#, blazor

I am new to Blazor, comming from ASP.net / Razor.

I am trying to find a way to load more content, once the user has reached the bottom of the page.
I could probably do it with jquery, however I found in asp.net that they dont mix very well (c# with js).

Any recommendation over how to achieve this?

Best,

J

Comment: Have you looked at the `Virtualize` component? See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Calculate Scroll Position:

First, you need to calculate the scroll position of the scrollable container. You can do this using JavaScript interop. Create a JavaScript function to check if the user has reached the bottom of the container:

```
function isScrollAtBottom(container) {
    return container.scrollHeight - container.scrollTop === container.clientHeight;
}
```

2- Call JavaScript Function from Blazor:

In your Blazor component, use the JSRuntime to call the JavaScript function and determine if the user has reached the bottom. You can use Blazor's IJSRuntime interface for JavaScript interop:

```
@page "/infinite-scroll"

<div @ref="scrollContainer" @onscroll="HandleScroll">
    <!-- Your existing content here -->
    @foreach (var item in items)
    {
        <p>@item</p>
    }
</div>

@code {
    private List<string> items = new List<string>
    {
        "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"
    };

    private ElementReference scrollContainer;

    [Inject]
    private IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

    private async Task HandleScroll()
    {
        var isAtBottom = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("isScrollAtBottom", scrollContainer);
        if (isAtBottom)
        {
            LoadMoreContent();
        }
    }

    private void LoadMoreContent()
    {
        // Load more content and append it to the items list
        items.Add("New Item");
        items.Add("Another New Item");
        // ... more loading logic
    }
}
```

3-Register JavaScript Function:

In your _Host.cshtml (or _Imports.razor), register the JavaScript function using the window object:

```
<script>
    window.isScrollAtBottom = function (container) {
        return container.scrollHeight - container.scrollTop === container.clientHeight;
    };
</script>
```

With this setup, the HandleScroll method is triggered when the user scrolls, and it checks whether the user has reached the bottom of the scrollable container. If they have, it calls the LoadMoreContent method to add more items to the list.

Comment: I just tried that, but loadmorecontent is never called. only the first 3 items are displayed at the bottom ofthe page now...

Comment: nvm; you weremissing: overflow:scroll on the div in style

Comment: thiswill now just add these items whenever we scroll, but thats not reaaaally what I want : i want them to be added once the user has reached the bottom of the scrollable page. how can I achieve that?

Comment: check my edit, hope that helps

Comment: [Polite] Doesn't the `Virtualize` component do the same thing?

Comment: Another thing to add: its better to use container.scrollHeight - container.scrollTop <= container.clientHeight) instead of just equal, i had missmatches by a pixel and then no reload. but that fixes this